# MongoDB into an Express Project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm new to Node.js, MongoDB and almost anything. I'd appreciate any help.

I've successfully installed MongoDB using the following command.

brew install mongodb

I got the following result.

==> Pouring mongodb-3.0.0.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
To have launchd start mongodb at login:
    ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mongodb/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then to load mongodb now:
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
    mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.0.0: 17 files, 152M

I'd be happy if you'd teach me what to do next.

What should I do to incorporate MongoDB into an Express project?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add the MongoDB package to your `package.json` file at the root of your Express project.

If you want to work with MongoDB using an ORM then use the package http://mongoosejs.com/

If you want to work with MongoDB using raw queries then use the package http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/node-js/